# How to get a return value from a post request in NextJs 9 Serverless

Tags: authentication, post, return-value, next.js, serverless

I'm building a serverless app using NextJs and I'm stuck on how I can get a return value that includes a user's JWT when making a post request to my DB. Everything works as expected but I can't get this one thing down.

In my login page, this is how I handle user-submitted data:

```js
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/login`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
})

console.log('successfully logged in')
console.log(res)
```

In my API, the way I return a value when making a request to `/api/login` is:

```js
return res.status(201).json({
  message: 'Account successfully signed in!',
  user,
  token
})
```

Now when I go to check my console.log in dev tools, here's what the response looks like:

```js
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: ReadableStream
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

Nothings there and I don't know why?

Comment: you are not sending any jwt on your POST request

Comment: Correct, when users login I want to generate a JWT server-side and send it back to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **fetch** body response, you should decode it by the type that you are expecting (in your case `json`).

```js
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/login`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
})
const data = await res.json(); // <--- this is the missing part

console.log('successfully logged in')
console.log(data)
```